# error :unknown command crunch

Tags: android, sdk, compiler-errors

i am using eclipse indigo version.i had to create a project in android 2.2 google API.but that was not installed in my system.so i installed the same and created a project sing that.but when i try to run the project it is showing many errors like unknown command crunch etc.i have searched in he google to solve the issue and came to know that i have to upgrade the SDK again.is it really needed becuase i do not have that much time.is there any other solution to solve this issue? please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Eclipse ADT plugin is out of sync with your downloaded SDK tools and platform-tools. Your ADT plugin is newer than the tools. Your only option is to update the tools to match your ADT plugin.